# To return a list of digits ofa negative number

Tags: python

I tried to convert a number into a list of its digits by converting the number into a linked list.It worked fine for positive numbers but it is not working for negative numbers:
I tried to do it in this way:

```
def number_to_list(number):
    head,tail = None,None
    for x in str(number):
        if not x.isdigit():
           a1 = x
           continue
        map(lambda:x,x*a1)
        node = Node(int(x))
        if head:
           tail.next = node
        else:
           head = node
        tail = node
    return head
```

when I call the function `head = number_to_list(-120)` and later `listutils.from_linked_list(head)` by using the library to which head is passed as argument it should return [-1,-2,0] but it is returning [].

Comment: Isn't the first digit of `-120` `1`, not `-1`?

Comment: Why should it return -1, -2, 0?

Comment: Is this alignment/whitespace what you actually have in your code?

Comment: Do you mean [-x for x in range(120)]?

Comment: @sundance I am trying just to consider '-' and then proceeding to the next step.

Comment: @Ramya: Why not detect if it's negative, and if yes, negate the number so that your algorithm works as expected and negate every digit separately?

Comment: Your `continue` statement will skip the rest of the loop body. And the `map` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @MxyL I am passing a 3-digit negative number,converting it to a linked list of its digits

Comment: The thing is, why do you think negative numbers have negative digits? That's just absurd... The digits of `-120` are `1`, `2` and `0`

Comment: @NiklasB. Well, I am asked to do it in that way I tried but failed to do so,So thought of approaching this.

Comment: @Ramya So do the requirements ask you to return `[-1, -2, 0]` or is that just what you want to return?

Comment: It should return a linked list in this way -1->-2->0@MxyL

Answer (score 1):

Given your description of the problem it is somewhat hard to guess what you're after. Maybe you can elaborate a little more on the context, otherwise we are pretty much left guessing. Anyway, here we go:

```
x = -120
[-int(d) if x < 0 else int(d) for d in str(abs(x))]
# [-1, -2, 0]
```